# Broadcast function in Numpy similar to matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, knn

So I am building a KNN for some larger datasets, and I am required to run Leave-one-out cross validation in order to choose the correct K, so speed is important.

I am trying to do the distance calculation via broadcasting.

---

The situation is: `X` is my training matrix, a 2D matrix with samples on the rows.  `Q` is my query matrix, or test data, also with samples on the rows.

I need to run something analogous to a matrix multiplication, where I match each row of Q with each column of `X.T` (x transpose), and build a `sample x sample` matrix, where each entry [i,j] is the distance of query sample i from training sample j.  Then I would sort and choose the mode of the classes from the first k samples.

---

Anyways, in matrix multiplication, numpy does exactly this...but instead of a distance calculation, it does a piecewise multiplication and sum (dot product).  If I could insert my distance function into that position instead, I think I would have a KNN distance calculation about as fast as a numpy matrix multiplication.

Is there a way to do this using broadcasting or some other numpy technique?

Maybe even a way to parallelize it?

---

Sample code:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.asarray([1.0,10.0,100.0])
x2 = np.asarray([40.0,60.0,80.0])
x3 = np.asarray([20.,30.,40.])
x = np.concatenate((x1.reshape(3,1),x2.reshape(3,1),x3.reshape(3,1)),axis=1)

y1 = np.asarray([4.0,88.0,35.0])
y2 = np.asarray([7.0,65.0,99.0])
y3 = np.asarray([40.0,13.0,27.0])
y = np.concatenate((y1.reshape(3,1),y2.reshape(3,1),y3.reshape(3,1)),axis=1)

def euclidean_distance(p1,p2): 
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((p1-p2)**2.0))
```

so, I might write:

```
distances = np.zeros((y.shape[0],x.shape[0]))
for i in range(y.shape[0]):
   for j in range(x.shape[0]):
       distances[i,j] = euclidean_distance(y[i,:],x[j,:])
```

And that is what I would then sort.  In the current for loop above, I would just choose my k nearest neighbors and find the class in that inner loop...but it would be much slower than calculating all the distances in a vectorized calculation.

Comment: Well, you can get distances with cdist : `from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist; distances = cdist(y,x)`. Not sure if this answers your question(s).

Comment: Your code above produces `(9, 1)` vectors as `x` and `y` - is that what you intended? Perhaps you meant to concatenate over the second axis rather than the first?

Comment: it gets me a little closer.  thanks man.  I also have to do a mahalanobis distance version, which requires that I do a matrix multiplication inside the distance calculation...

Comment: @ali_m  got it working.

Comment: Looks like `mahalanobis` dist calculation is supported too - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis.html

Comment: Oh, no way.  well, I guess ideally I'd implement it myself.  I think I might be required to use my own code...but that will get it done for now...thanks

Comment: *"I might be required to use my own code"* - is this homework?

Comment: @ali_m  choosing the optimal k for the KNN on the MNIST dataset is the homework.  There are 20,000 datasamples with 783 columns (150 relevant after PCA)...so what is important is that I broadcast the distance calculation...and do the mahalanobis with my own code.

Answer (score 2):

As Divakar already mentioned, the simplest option is probably [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

distances = cdist(y, x)                 # Euclidean
distances = cdist(y, x, 'mahalanobis')  # Mahalanobis
```

This is single-threaded but fast. You could also use [`np.linalg.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html):

```
distances = np.linalg.norm(y[:, None, :] - x[None, :, :], axis=2)   # Euclidean
```

This broadcasts out the difference calculation over pairs of rows in `x` and `y` to create an intermediate array of shape `(3, 3, 3)`, then computes the Euclidean norm over the last axis. This is multithreaded, but involves constructing an intermediate array that might be quite large if `x` and `y` have lots of rows (it also doesn't exploit the symmetry of the distance matrix).

It would be fairly straightforward to generalize the second method to compute Mahalanobis distance instead of Euclidean distance (I'll leave this part for you to figure out...).

Answer (score 1):

I would:

- repeat+reshape both arrays to a 3D-form (3 x len(x) x len(y))
- take the difference, sqare, and sum along the axis=0
- now you have a 2D-Array of distances and can take the min along the appropriate axis

does this help you? Or I'll try to write it more explicit...

comment to step 2: you don't have to take the sqrt to find the minimum, you can just as well minimize the square

Comment: right, course--forgot about that.  Either way, the important thing is that it isn't running the loop in python, and the complexity stays in n^2.

Answer (score 1):

Try broadcasting to take a cross-difference:

```
d = np.sqrt(np.sum((y[:,None,:]-x[None,:,:])**2,axis=-1))
```

my test script

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.asarray([1.0,10.0,100.0])
x2 = np.asarray([40.0,60.0,80.0])
x3 = np.asarray([20.,30.,40.])
x = np.concatenate([i.reshape(-1,1) for i in [x1,x2,x3]], axis=1)
# see also column_stack

y1 = np.asarray([4.0,88.0,35.0])
y2 = np.asarray([7.0,65.0,99.0])
y3 = np.asarray([40.0,13.0,27.0])
"""
y1 = np.asarray([4.0,88.0])   # test 2d y
y2 = np.asarray([7.0,99.0])
y3 = np.asarray([13.0,27.0])
"""
y = np.concatenate([i.reshape(-1,1) for i in [y1,y2,y3]], axis=1)

def euclidean_distance(p1,p2):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((p1-p2)**2.0))

distances = np.zeros((y.shape[0],x.shape[0]))
for i in range(y.shape[0]):
   for j in range(x.shape[0]):
       distances[i,j] = euclidean_distance(y[i,:],x[j,:])

print (distances)

d = np.sqrt(np.sum((y[:,None,:]-x[None,:,:])**2,axis=-1))
print(d)
```

producing

```
1230:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack35961972.py 
[[  38.70400496   54.2678542   120.60265337]
 [  90.79096871   79.98749902   33.13608305]
 [  68.45436436   46.42197755   68.95650803]]
[[  38.70400496   54.2678542   120.60265337]
 [  90.79096871   79.98749902   33.13608305]
 [  68.45436436   46.42197755   68.95650803]]
```